# Add 2008 DC to 2003 - domain schema upgrade failed

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, active-directory, domain-controller

I'm trying to add the first 2008 R2 DC to an existing 2003 domain (upgraded to 2003 functionality).  I've followed the steps from microsoft which are clarified by this post:
[2003 DC AD upgrade to 2008 on second server migration plan](https://serverfault.com/questions/367174/2003-dc-ad-upgrade-to-2008-on-second-server-migration-plan)
While running adprep /forestprep I lost my connection and wasn't able to resume or remote control that session, so I couldn't see the end result of the command.

Rerunning adprep /forestprep indicates that the process has already been completed successfully.  After finishing the rest of the steps (/domainprep ... and /gpprep, etc), the 2008 server fails on dcpromo.  The error message is the same "you need to run forestprep first"

So the situation I'm in is that I can't rerun /forestprep, but my Registry key still reads schemaVer=30.  Should I have staged forest upgrades?  Any ideas how to get my schema ver to 44 at this point?

Comment: There are no schema changes required to join a 2008 server to a 2003 domain. I think you meant to say you cannot run DC promo on the 2008 server to make it a DC?
Are you sure you ran the ADPREP from the 2008 media to get 2008 schema and not the adprep from 2003 media?
Logs from the ADPREP command are saved at C:\Windows\Debug\Adprep\Logs. Do you see any errors in those logs?
Is this a single or multi domain forest? How many DC's in each domain?
Has the schema change replicated throughout the domain? Check the registry value you already mentioned on each DC. Also run: repadmin /replsummary

Comment: Yes, I meant dcpromo (my mistake).  I did run adprep from the appropriate media (2008 r2), but I couldn't find the log location.  It's a single domain forest.  I have some direction now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try running through dcdiag /fix and possibly using the netdiag /fix (might have to download netdiag separately, it's been a while..) from the 2003 DC. After that, try running the /forestprep and /domainprep again